# item counter within enumerate

Tags: enumerate, counters

I want to customize items from a list within the enumerate environment, using a counter that is followed up in each list.

Here's how I did it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{counter}

List 1 

\begin{enumerate}[label=Ex.\arabic{counter}] \stepcounter{counter}
    \item Some text \stepcounter{counter}
    \item Some text \stepcounter{counter}
    \item Some text \stepcounter{counter}
\end{enumerate}

List 2

\begin{enumerate}[label=Ex.\arabic{counter}] \stepcounter{counter}
    \item Some text \stepcounter{counter}
    \item Some text \stepcounter{counter}
    \item Some text \stepcounter{counter}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Another way to do it is by customizing each item:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{counter}

List 1 

\begin{enumerate}
    \item[Ex.\stepcounter{counter}\arabic{counter}] Some text 
    \item[Ex.\stepcounter{counter}\arabic{counter}] Some text
    \item[Ex.\stepcounter{counter}\arabic{counter}] Some text 
\end{enumerate}

List 2

\begin{enumerate}
    \item[Ex.\stepcounter{counter}\arabic{counter}] Some text 
    \item[Ex.\stepcounter{counter}\arabic{counter}] Some text
    \item[Ex.\stepcounter{counter}\arabic{counter}] Some text 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the only way I can stepcounter each item is by using the command every time I create a new item. However, **I want to avoid using the same command every time and just define from the begining that each item should step the counter**, I'm looking to do something like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\stepcounter{counter}Ex.\arabic{counter}]
    \item Some text 
    \item Some text
    \item Some text 
\end{enumerate}
```

But that doesn't work.

Also, if possible, I'd like to avoid creating a new command for "item" such as

```
\newcommand{\newitem}{\item[\stepcounter{counter}Ex.\arabic{counter}]}
```

Because I might neeed to create a list that shouldn't follow the same count.

**Also** I know I can delimit from which number to start like this:

```
List 1 

\begin{enumerate}[label=Ex.\arabic*] 
    \item Some text 
    \item Some text 
    \item Some text
\end{enumerate}

List 2

\begin{enumerate}[label=Ex.\arabic*, start=4]
    \item Some text 
    \item Some text
    \item Some text 
\end{enumerate}
```

But I want to avoid that too, though maybe it is much to ask.

Thank you

Comment: Erh did you read the enumitem manual? `label=Ex. \arabic*` seems to do what you want

Comment: The problem is everytime I create a new list the count resets, and I know I can delimit from which number to start, but I wanted to avoid that too. Thanks.

Comment: That is not clear from your question, please rephrase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\arabic*` - [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s way of using the appropriate counter formatting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=Ex.\arabic*]
  \item Some text
  \item Some text
  \item Some text
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

You may be better off defining your own list type, which could include the `resume` option to resume counting if you break up your list with interspersed text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercises]{%
  label=Ex.\arabic*,
  resume
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercises}
  \item Some text
  \item Some text
  \item Some text
\end{exercises}

Some text in between the two lists.

\begin{exercises}
  \item Some text
  \item Some text
  \item Some text
\end{exercises}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is everytime I create a new list the count resets, and I know I can delimit from which number to start, but I wanted to avoid that too. Thanks.

Comment: @Darvid: I've updated the answer to include a solution to your new problem (of resuming a list that may have been broken up by other components).

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!